# Web based remote administration of Windows user accounts?

Tags: windows, users, ntlm, accounts

We're looking for a simple web based admin tool to allow trusted users to create windows user accounts via a web based interface.  It should also give regular users the ability to change their passwords.

I'm familiar with IISADMPWD from IIS 6, which is very clunky and only provides the ability for users to change their passwords.

Does anyone know of a third party tool that provides a web UI to manage user accounts?  I know you can do this via remote desktop, but for a simple task like user creation it would be great if it could be handled remotely using a simpler interface.

Thanks,

Darren.

Comment: A very interesting question. The idea of being able to administer users via a web interface is a nice idea and could be very useful if you had administrators outside of your normal organisation.

Answer (score 1):

I believe Quest ActiveRoles product line can do this.  I can't recall offhand though if it is web-based or not for the user provisioning.  And it isn't cheap.

Another solution for free would be to install the adminpak tools, give them the proper delegated rights in ADUC, and then create a custom based MMC console for them to use for ADUC like below:

c/p from another site:

1. Open mmc - File - Add/Remove Snap-in - Add - select ADUC  - Add - Close - OK.
2. Select desired OU - right click on OU - New Window from here.
3. After that limit user access to only that window: File - Options - Console mode: User mode - limited access, single window.
4. Save console: File - Save As
5. Test console
6. Give console (msc file) to user

Comment: ActiveRoles is an excellent tool, but as you say, it isn't cheap.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [ADManager Plus](http://www.manageengine.com/products/ad-manager/).  It isn't as expensive as ActiveRoles, but it will do everything you requested, plus a [whole lot more](http://www.manageengine.com/products/ad-manager/features.html).  Plus, there's a 30 day free [trial](http://www.manageengine.com/products/ad-manager/download.html)!

We've been using it for a while now to manage several domains and have no complaints.

Answer (score 1):

Users can change their own passwords by doing a 3 finger salute (cntrl-alt-del) and selecting change password, no special software needed.

As for the admin, unless you really need a web-interface, what is wrong with [AdminPak](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=86b71a4f-4122-44af-be79-3f101e533d95)?

Answer (score 0):

For the first part, allowing trusted users to create windows user accounts, create a Taskpad, which is a regular, Windows supported, way to do what you want. It allows you to give the trusted users fine-grained permissions for the task. Details can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa815361(VS.85).aspx), [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa815351(VS.85).aspx), and [here](http://www.petri.co.il/create_taskpads_for_ad_operations.htm) (use Google for more).

For the password change part, users can already do that. Just educate them, there is no need for added complexity on your part.